# Generating a DOC or DOCX using MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am working on a project where I need to create a Word file. For this purpose, I am using MigraDoc library for C#.

Using this library, I am easily able to generate a RTF file by writing :

```
Document document = CreateDocument();
RtfDocumentRenderer rtf = new RtfDocumentRenderer();
rtf.Render(document, "test.rtf", null);
Process.Start("test.rtf");
```

But the requirement now asks me to get a DOC or DOCX file rather than a RTF file. Is there a way to generate a DOC or DOCX file using MigraDoc? And if so, how may I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MigraDoc cannot generate DOC or DOCX files. Since MigraDoc is open source, you could add a renderer for DOCX if you have the knowledge and the time.

MigraDoc as it is cannot generate DOC/DOCX, but maybe you can invoke an external conversion tool after generating the RTF file.
I don't know any such tools. Word can open RTF quickly and so far our customers never complained about getting RTF, not DOC or DOCX.

Update (2019-07-29): The website mentions "Word", but this only refers to RTF. There never was an implementation for .DOC or .DOCX.

Answer (score 2):

It seems no any **MigraDoc** renders that support **DOC** or **DOCX** formats.

On documentation page we can see one **MigraDoc** feature:

> Supports different output formats (PDF, Word, HTML, any printer supported by Windows)

But seems documentation says about **RTF** format that perfectly works with Word. I have reviewed [MigraDoc repository](https://github.com/empira/MigraDoc) and I do not see any **DOC** renders. We can use only **RTF** converter for Word supporting. So we can't generate **DOC** file directly using this package.

But we can convert **RTF** to **DOC** or **DOCX** easily (and for free) using [FreeSpire.Doc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.Doc/) nuget package.

Full code example is here:

```
using MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel;
using MigraDoc.RtfRendering;
using Spire.Doc;
using System.IO;

namespace MigraDocTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Generate RTF (using MigraDoc)
                var migraDoc = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document();
                var section = migraDoc.AddSection();
                var paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
                paragraph.AddFormattedText("Hello World!", TextFormat.Bold);
                var rtfDocumentRenderer = new RtfDocumentRenderer();
                rtfDocumentRenderer.Render(migraDoc, stream, false, null);

                // Convert RTF to DOCX (using Spire.Doc)
                var spireDoc = new Spire.Doc.Document();
                spireDoc.LoadFromStream(stream, FileFormat.Auto);
                spireDoc.SaveToFile("D:\\example.docx", FileFormat.Docx );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft's DocumentFormat.OpenXML library which has a NuGet package.

Comment: Have you got an example?